# Differences between "make" and "do"

Tags: word-difference, do-vs-make

In my class, my teacher told us that, we should find the differences between ***"make"*** and ***"do".***

I'm Vietnamese so I'm confused with this question! Can you help me?

And the similar between them is the meaning? Right?

Comment: There is a sea of difference between the two. This was probably an introductory course, so you should just heed your teacher. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to answer this without writing a book!

Comment: Because so many expressions using *make* and *do* are idiomatic, there's no easy guide. As a rough guide *make* is more often used in contexts such as manufacturing and constructing while *do* relates more to actions and occupations. There are numerous online sites dealing with the use of the two words, such as: https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/do-make-expressions/

Comment: Do you have an example sentence that would use one of the words?  That would help in determining what the differences would be in that case.

Comment: @M.A.R. It's difficult, though, because in some languages *do* and *make* translate to the same word (*faire* in French, for example), and in other languages the boundary between the two is drawn in different places.  So it's really a classic ELL question.

Comment: In Vietnamese, "make" is something like "tạo ra", whereas "do" means "thực hiện"